# Convert PostgreSQL Query to GORM Query

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

How do I convert the following SQL query to GORM?

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('lexeme word');
```

Or equivalently:

```
SELECT * FROM files, plainto_tsquery('lexeme word') q WHERE tsv @@ q;
```

I can use `.Exec()`:

```
err := d.Connection.DB.Exec("SELECT * FROM scenes WHERE tsv @@ plainto_tsquery(?);",text).Error
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

This query doesn't allow me to get an array of data and work with it.
Unfortunately, I could not find a solution using the GORM documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Raw()` for raw SQL query

```
db.Raw("SELECT id, name, age FROM users WHERE name = ?", 3).Scan(&result)
```

Official [doc](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Raw-SQL) for about raw SQL query